# Continuity of tangent vector

Tags: geometry

I am given a parametrised curve $r(t)=(t,0)$ for$\: t<0, (t,y(t)),$ for$\:0\leq t \leq 1  $ and $ (t,1) $ for $\: t>1$.

There is a gap between the line y=0 and y=1. I am told to construct a function y(t) to join the lines smoothly. That is $r(t)$ should be continuous, tangent vector $T(t)$ and curvature $k(t) $ all continuous as well.

There's a hint suggesting to choose a polynomial with degree 5 and so we'll have 6 unknown constants. First consider the case of simply joining two parts by a straight line of polynomial of degree 1. That will be $y(t)=t$ since it satisfies $y(0)=0, y(1)=1.$
Now I need to consider a polynomial of degree 3 (e.g. $at^3+bt^2+t)$ and solve for extra two unknown constants using the condition that the tangent vector has to be continuous at $t=0, t=1$. 
I computed an expression of polynomial for tangent vector at points $t=o, t=1$ but I don't quite understand what should I do now to find the values of constants. What continuity tells me?
Some of my workings:

$v(t)=(t,at^3+bt^2+t)$

$v'(t)=(1,3at^2+2bt+1)$

$||v'(t)||=\sqrt{1+(3at^2+2tb+1)^2}$

So the tangent vector $T(t)=\frac{v'(t)}{||v'(t)||}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(3at^2+2tb+1)^2}}
(1,3at^2+2bt+1)$

$T(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)$

$T(1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(3a+2b+1)^2}}(0,3a+2b+1)$

For curvature bit which is next I think the point is to equate it to 0 since at t=0 and t=1 it is supposed to be not bending as it joins straight horizontal lines.

Comment: You mean $t<0$ in your first case, don't you?

Comment: You have 6 unknown coefficients, and six equations you can write in terms of them because you want to match the position, the slope, and the curvature at at two points. ("Matching" is another way to say these quantities are continuous at the two points.) What are the six equations? This gives a system of 6 equations in 6 unknowns, so it could have a unique solution.

Comment: Two equations should be 
y(0)=0
y(1)=1
Two associated with tangents and two with curvature. With curvature I think I say k(0)=k(1)=0 .
I don't know what to do with tangents though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you restricted to polynomials? Otherwise $y(t)=f(t)/\bigl(f(t)+f(1-t)\bigr)$  with $$f(t):=\begin{cases}e^{-1/t},&\text{for $ t>0$}\\
0,&\text{for $\leq0$}
\end{cases}$$
 will do the job.  Just verify that $y(t)=0$ if $t\leq0$, $y(t)=1$ if $t\geq1$, $y(]0,1[)=]0,1[$ and $y'(t)>0$ for $0<t<1$.

Comment: Not really. The polynomial probably makes it simpler for me to solve, given that we have just started geometry. For instance I don't understand why that y(t) would work.

Comment: It might work but I have no clue why we chose that particular function. 
Do you know what should I do to proceed with polynomials?

Comment: Yes: don't.  Did you plot my provided $y$?.

Comment: Yeah it looks like what I need But yet again I would never get it myself.
Just knowing an alternative answer does not help me understanding.

Answer (score 0):

First look for the obvious, that is a symmetric polynomial of degree $5$ satisfying with $f(1/2)=1/2$, $f'(1/2)=f''(1/2)=0$; you'll end up with $f(x)=6x^5-5x^3+15x/8$. Now $y(t)=f(t-1/2)+1/2=6t^5-15t^4+10t^3$ satisfies all conditions.